# jQuery toggle (jQuery UI) and Bootstrap Layout Breaking

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

So I am having a little issue with jQuery.

I currently have a page that contains a form and when it's submitted a button is shown that can toggle content. It also sets a cookie so if the user revisits the page they don't need to fill in the form again and can access the content.

My issue is; when the toggle is clicked, the layout of the content shown isn't correct. Below is a little clip to show what's happening. The column widths aren't correct and the content inside the toggled content isn't within the container which overlaps the parallax effect in the hero.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: After doing some troubleshooting, when the window is smaller the parallax effect works and doesn't overlap the hero.

As my knowledge of jQuery is very limited, do I need to get the height of the hidden div before it's hidden or something along those lines?

[Video](https://vimeo.com/295976484)

```html
<main id="main" class="site-main row">
  <?php if (!isset( $_COOKIE['presentation'] )) {  ?>
    <div class="main col-md-12 toggle_content_hide" role="main">
      <?php the_field( "presentation" );?>
      <a class="button" id="toggle">Toggle</a>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle_content row" style="display: none;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <aside id="secondary" class="col-md-3" role="complementary">
              <ul class="sticker">
                //Stuff
              </ul>
            </aside>
            <div class="main col-md-9" role="main">
              //Presentations
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <div class="toggle_content row">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <aside id="secondary" class="col-md-3" role="complementary">
                <ul class="sticker">
                  //Stuff
                </ul>
              </aside>
              <div class="main col-md-9" role="main">
                //Presentations
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </main>
```

```js
$("#toggle").click(function() {
  $(".toggle_content_hide").toggle("scale");
  $(".toggle_content").toggle("scale");
});
```

[GIST](https://gist.github.com/paddywinz/5f2525afc14965c7f9e86f67e75c6352)